# Should i ignore the __builtin_prefetch() function or replace it?

Tags: c++, linux

When i am porting the codes from linux to win32, it comes to the __builtin_prefetch() function.

Then i found, its business is prefetching the cache data. 
as the [gcc onlinedoc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) says : If the target does not support data prefetch, the address expression is evaluated if it includes side effects but no other code is generated and GCC does not issue a warning.

it means the function may do nothing actually? 
So if i do not consider the overhead, can i ignore the function ? And, is there some similar function in vs2008, so i could use to replace it ?

```
void __builtin_prefetch (const void *addr, ...);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefetching is strictly for performance, you can ignore it.

http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/prefetch.html

Most of the time modern processors will detect the access patterns to memory and prefetch data speculatively ahead of anticipated use (hardware prefetch).  The reason for prefetching is the CPU is much faster than memory, a cache miss takes many cycles to go to DRAM and get the data.  The _builtin_prefetch is a software prefetch (if the target machine you are compiling to supports it), and is just a hint to the hardware that you might need the data at that address later on so it gets the memory request going and hide the long latency.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need it, then remove it. The functions _*builtin**, obviously, are used only for the GCC compiler. On the other hand, if you really need the function, more than likely you have to replace it with your own equivalent function.